# Getting records from mysql which are in mm/dd/yy format

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL column which holds expiration dates in mm/dd/yy format.

How can I get records that are going to expire within 2 days from today?

Comment: Is the column really a character string in that format?  Or is it a date (or time) field?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention here expire date column is a varchar datatype where i'm storin end date selected using data picker

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CAST(EXPIREDATE AS DATETIME)
    BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sqldate/sql-date-add-days.shtml

Comment: haha thx, those compare, adding stuff always messes up my mind

Comment: No prob. I added a cast for his field (looks like it may be a string) and an enhanced range check.